# Remove persistent notification of an app without disabling all of its notifications

Tags: notifications, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

The latest Pushbullet update (v17.0.4) for Android  has added a persistent notification to my notification drawer. The app indicates that I can remove the notification by enabling Pushbullet in the notification access settings. However, I can't seem to find these settings in my Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.2.2 with Samsung's ROM.

Are there notification access settings in Android 4.2.2? If so, where did Samsung bury them in the settings?

If there are no such settings in Android 4.2.2, is there a way to remove persistent notifications without affecting Pushbullet's functionality (such as through an Xposed module)?

EDIT: 
To clarify, I don't want to disable **all** notifications for this app, it would defeat the purpose of the app. I want to disable the persistent notification that now shows up. It is supposedly necessary in order to allow certain features, now that the accessibility service has been removed.

Comment: Yes, it is rooted. Thank you for testing it. This looks like what I want. I will test it and see if it works without removing the app functionality the persistent notification supposedly preserves. It's possible that removing the notification will cause Android to kill whatever background process it's allowing to persist, but we'll see.

Comment: @Sophie Jane :  Your post was looking at disabling persistent notification without affecting functionality.  This possibility has been categorically denied by developer as posted by me. This is a definitive, conclusive answer that cannot be disputed coming from the developer. Hence, my request is to accept the answer so that viewers will accept it with  more credibility.  Else it would simply remain a voted answer.  Of  course,  this is entirely your choice  to accept it or not. Thanks

Comment: @beeshyams No single reply here has definitively answered all the questions posed in the body of my question, and so I don't feel a best accepted answer is warranted, as of yet. Firelord's has come closest,  as I installed NotifyClean and successfully removed the persistent notification without affecting most of Pushbullet's functionality (I have not tested SMS syncing yet,  but I suspect it will not work as per your quotes of the developer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is rooted you can install Xposed and install [Notify Clean](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.defim.apk.notifyclean) which allows to disable a specific notification which matches some text filter.

[Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) can only turn off notifications for whole app so it cannot help in this case.

Comment: Please provide a **detailed** use-case of NotifyClean for the goal in question. Also, does it address the [concern raised by OP](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127888/remove-persistent-notification-of-an-app-without-disabling-all-of-its-notificati#comment158952_127888): "*I will test it and see if it works without removing the app functionality the persistent notification supposedly preserves. It's possible that removing the notification will cause Android to kill whatever background process it's allowing to persist*"?

Comment: @Fire lord thanks for edit.  Can you please direct me to page which shows how to edit?  All my posts are mobile based  so will not have full keyboard functions of Laptop, but would like to try.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the case of Pushbullet, if you don't want to use SMS sync, you can turn off it from Pushbullet settings and the notification will disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling persistent notification would affect the functionality of app, as confirmed by app's developer in reply to my query.

[My query](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63664459&postcount=229):

> If I disable persistent notification does it affect the functionality[?]

Developer's ([guzba](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=4374844)) [reply](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=63664518&postcount=230):

> I'm working toward not needing the notification. It can affect functionality right now though if you use SMS sync or Universal copy & paste because without the notification, Android can (and probably will) kill our app making them no longer work. This is less bad with SMS sync since I can make sure it's running for incoming messages, but will be potentially functionality-ending for Android initiated Universal copy & paste.

Source: [Pushbullet](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=63664518)  at XDA Developers forum.

Comment: You ended up posting at [wrong place](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127888/remove-persistent-notification-of-an-app-without-disabling-all-of-its-notificati/127964?noredirect=1#comment159008_127964). Anyhow, you can edit any post by using the URL: `http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/POST_ID/edit`. You can find the POST_ID under the share option. For e.g., it is 128003 for your answer so the URL would be `http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/128003/edit`. Alternatively, comment `[edit]` (without backticks) on your post to get the direct link for editing, such as [edit].

Answer (score 1):

Since the device is are rooted, you may like to give [Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) app, a try.

This additionally offers integration with automation apps  and that may offer more flexibility in customizing app behavior.

Comment: Again, why are you suggesting this app? Please justify the recommendation and offer alternatives.

Comment: The suggested app disables all notifications for specific apps, and so is not relevant (see my edit in the question above).

Comment: @Sophie Jane. Sorry missed that portion of question. If you don't find any app or a way  to access settings and are willing to try automation let me know and will try to figure a way

Comment: beeshyams, when suggesting an app or a product here, strive to follow the guidelines mentioned here: [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/a/5330) I believe you would be able to save yourself from the comments asking explanation for justifications (which indeed are valid) *et al*.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly,  no one has yet mentioned that notification access settings do not exist in Android 4.2.2 (my first question in the question post body above), having been introduced for 4.4. Evidence: I found notification access settings on my device running 4.4, but not on my 4.2.2 device. Thus, the only solution is to remove the persistent notification, which I have done with NotifyClean as suggested by Firelord.