# Hide a persistent notification altogether (without proprietary software)

Tags: notifications

I'd like to hide a persistent notification of an application (an IRC client) but would like to keep all the event notification (for example, I'd still like to receive a notification when I'm mentioned in the channel).

There was [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/127888/remove-persistent-notification-of-an-app-without-disabling-all-of-its-notificati) question which suggested two proprietary applications to do this. Still, I'd rather refrain from installing closed-source applications, as my CyanogenMod installation has no user-space closed-source blobs.

Is it possible to remove the persistent notification without installing proprietary blobs?

I'm running CM 13.0. My phone is rooted and I have Xposed installed.